how to recreate new instance of GetxController in flutter
in flutter i have 3 pages
PAGE 1
PAGE 2
PAGE 3
every page has a GetxController that initialized when navigate to that page and disposed when close page
in PAGE 3 I have to renavigate to PAGE 2 to show another data , so my plan is
  await Get.delete<PAGE2Controller>();
          await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 300));

      Get.until((route) {
       

        return Get.currentRoute == '/PAGE1';
      });


      
      Get.to(PAGE2());

but after navigate to PAGE 2 the PAGE2Controller initialized and suddenly Deleted from memory
how can I prevent to delete it after initialize it again.

Your writing is not clear enough. Let's me confirm your problem: You delete Page2Controller --> Navigate back to page 1 --> Navigate to page 2. The problem you are facing is Page2Controller was deleted twice, right?
